# Como fazer vários projetos terem o mesmo evento pós-compilação?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tenho uma solução no Visual Studio com 277 projetos. E gostaria de que todos tivessem tivessem o mesmo evento de pós-compilação. Basicamente, eles executariam um executavel que esta na pasta da aplicação.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei uma solução em uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295583/221800). Não sei se ela te atende mas é um caminho. Na mesma página existem outras soluções, inclusive de [*plugin*](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0d1dbfd7-ed8a-40af-ae39-281bfeca2334/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 2):

Crie um programa pra abrir cada projeto e então adicionar a seção de pós-compilação.

Ficaria algo desse tipo:

```
foreach (var caminhoDoProjeto in Directory.GetFiles(
    "caminho/da/solucao",
    "*.csproj",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(caminhoDoProjeto)));
    XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
    var event = xdoc.Descendants(msbuild + "PostBuildEvent").SingleOrDefault();
    if (event == null)
    {
        var group = new XElement(msbuild + "PropertyGroup");
        event = new XElement(msbuild + "PostBuildEvent");
        group.Add(event);
        xdoc.Root.Add(group);
    }
    event.Value = postEventText;
    xdoc.Save();
}
```

P.S. **Faça backup** e vai debugando isso ai pra ter certeza que não vai dar nenhum problema... sem garantias, eu NÃO TESTEI.

Answer (score 2):

O visual studio lhe permite criar eventos pós compilação(postbuild events) com a utilização deste recurso você pode criar arquivos bat para proceder com oque lhe for de interesse, o ruim é que mesmo que o script de postbuild seja o mesmo você terá de faze-lo(copy/past) em todos os projetos da sua solução, segue um exemplo para você customizar.

```
    <PostBuildEvent>
      MOVE /Y "$(TargetDir)something.file1" "$(ProjectDir)something.file1" start XCOPY /Y /R "$(SolutionDir)SomeConsoleApp\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*"     "$(ProjectDir)App_Data\Consoles\SomeConsoleApp\"
    </PostBuildEvent>
```

Comment: Já tinha pensado nisso. Mas o problema são as dependências, aonde por exemplo, ao compilar o projeto x, ele chama o y, o z, o k....